# Always java.lang.NullPointerException with android device (Lenovo and NEC and all devices running android 2.3.x)

Tags: android

Always java.lang.NullPointerException with Android device (Lenovo and NEC and all devices running Android 2.3.x)

I am very much wondering why my game always error at java.lang.NullPointerException with android device(Lenovo and NEC and all devices running android 2.3.x). But it's working very very well with all Samsung Device I tested.

Please see attached the print screen that I captured from Crashes & ANRs in Play Store, and my game link in play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull

[image]

## Here is my full code(color_q_easy_1.java)

```
package kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class color_q_easy_1 extends Activity{
private AdView adView;
//SQLite Method
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

    private Button score_board = null;

    Dialog myDialog;

    private CountDownTimer aCounter = null;


    private MediaPlayer ohmygod;
    private MediaPlayer win;

    private ImageView play_home, play_now, play_again;
    private TextView l_title;
    TextView timer, l_timer, l_q, q;
    private int screen;

    private RelativeLayout drag;
    private RelativeLayout drop;

    //Score
    private TextView TxtScore = null;
    private TextView TxtScore_inCorrect = null;
    private int correct = 0;
    private int incorrect = 0;

    private Animation end_time, in; 

    private TextView red, blue, yellow, black, white, pink, chocolate, gray;

    private TextView red_target, blue_target, yellow_target, black_target, white_target, gray_target, pink_target, chocolate_target;

    public CharSequence dragData;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SimpleDateFormat" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
Random rnd = new Random();
screen = (int) rnd.nextInt(6)+1;

switch(screen)
{
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1);
    break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1_a);
    break;
    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1_b);
    break;
    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1_c);
    break;
    case 5:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1_d);
    break;
    case 6:
        setContentView(R.layout.color_q_easy_1_e);
    break;
}

adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "96ffc9a995384d59");
final AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adsView);
ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/TRIFORCE.ttf");
Typeface typeFace1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/CHILLER.TTF");

end_time = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.time_up);
in = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(color_q_easy_1.this, true);

drag = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag);
drop = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drop);

final MediaPlayer time_up = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.time_up);
ohmygod = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ohmygod);
win = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.kid_cheerring);

//speakWords("Well Done.");
final MediaPlayer dragdrop = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.dragcolorboxdropintocolorname);
int timeout = 300;
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
{
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
    color_q_easy_1.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
     {
         public void run()
         {
             dragdrop.start();
         }
        });
      }
  }, timeout);

score_board = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sore_baord);
score_board.setVisibility(View.GONE);

l_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l_title);
l_title.setTypeface(typeFace);

//Hide Play Again, Go Home Button
final RelativeLayout gameEnd = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_ended);
gameEnd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
play_home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_home);
play_home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
play_again = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_again);
play_again.setVisibility(View.GONE);
play_now = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_now);
play_now.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(screen == 1)
{
    //views to drag
    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
    blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    black = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.black);
    white = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.white);

    //views to drop onto
    blue_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue_target);
    black_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.black_target); 
    white_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.white_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    blue.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    black.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    white.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    blue_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    black_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    white_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}
if(screen == 2)
{
    //views to drag
     red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
     blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
     black = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.black);
     white = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.white);

    //views to drop onto
    red_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red_target);
    blue_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue_target); 
    black_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.black_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    blue.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    black.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    white.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    red_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    blue_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    black_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}
if(screen == 3)
{
    //views to drag
    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
    blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    yellow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    white = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.white);

    //views to drop onto
    blue_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue_target);
    red_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red_target);
    yellow_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    blue.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    yellow.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    white.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    blue_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    red_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    yellow_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}
if(screen == 4)
{
    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
    blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    yellow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    gray = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray);

    //views to drop onto
    red_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red_target);
    gray_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray_target);
    yellow_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    blue.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    yellow.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    gray.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    red_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    gray_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    yellow_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}
if(screen == 5)
{
    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
    yellow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    pink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pink);
    gray = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray);

    //views to drop onto
    yellow_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellow_target);
    gray_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray_target);
    pink_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pink_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    yellow.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    pink.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    gray.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    yellow_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    gray_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    pink_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}
if(screen == 6)
{
    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
    pink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pink);
    chocolate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chocolate);
    gray = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray);

    //views to drop onto
    chocolate_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chocolate_target);
    gray_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gray_target);
    pink_target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pink_target);

    //set touch listeners
    red.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    pink.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    chocolate.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    gray.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    chocolate_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    gray_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    pink_target.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}

TextView scoreText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreText1);
scoreText1.setTypeface(typeFace1);
TextView scoreText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreText2);
scoreText2.setTypeface(typeFace1);
TxtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_correct);
TxtScore.setTypeface(typeFace1);

TxtScore_inCorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_incorrect);
TxtScore_inCorrect.setTypeface(typeFace1);

//Timer
l_q = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l_q);
q = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q);
l_q.setTypeface(typeFace1);
q.setTypeface(typeFace1);
timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
timer.setTypeface(typeFace1);
l_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l_timer);
l_timer.setTypeface(typeFace1);

aCounter = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        timer.setText("" +new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(new Date(millisUntilFinished)));
        if((millisUntilFinished / 1000)<=5 )
        {
            timer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            time_up.start();
        }
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        //timer.setText("Time's up!");
        timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        drag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        drop.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        RelativeLayout gameEnd = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_ended);
        gameEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        play_home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); play_home.startAnimation(in);
        play_again.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); play_again.startAnimation(in);

        //l_title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        l_title.setText("a");
        l_title.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
        l_title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.time_up);
        l_title.startAnimation(end_time);
        ohmygod.start();
        //Insert into DB
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(color_q_easy_1.this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

        // Data del trov insert
        String level = "Easy";
        String failed = "Fail";
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int level_step_a = 1;
        int level_step_b = 0;
        int percentage = 0;
        ////String correct = TxtScore.getText().toString();
        ////String incorrect = TxtScore_inCorrect.getText().toString();
        //Get DATE & TIME

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        mySQLiteAdapter.insert_COLOR(level, A, B, formattedDate, percentage, failed, level_step_a, level_step_b);

        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        play_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //show score board if tested all picture
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull", "kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.color_level_selection_q_easy");
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        play_again.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //show score board if tested all picture
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull", "kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.color_q_easy_1");
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
 };
 aCounter.start();
}

/**
 * ChoiceTouchListener will handle touch events on draggable views
 *
 */
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /*
         * Drag details: we only need default behavior
         * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
         * - shadow can be tailored
         */
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        //start dragging the item touched
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
} 

/**
 * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
 * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
 * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
 *
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        //no action necessary
        //Speech Drag Object
        //View textSpeech = (View) event.getLocalState();
        //TextView drag_speech = (TextView) textSpeech;
        //speakWords(drag_speech.getText().toString());
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        //no action necessary
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
        //no action necessary
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

        //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        //view dragged item is being dropped on
        TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
        //view being dragged and dropped
        TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
        //checking whether first character of dropTarget equals first character of dropped
       // if(dropTarget.getText().toString().charAt(0) == dropped.getText().toString().charAt(0))
        if(dropTarget.getText().toString() == dropped.getText().toString())
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Drawable txt = (Drawable) dropped.getBackground();
            dropTarget.setBackgroundDrawable(txt);
            dropTarget.setText(dropTarget.getText().toString());
            dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
            if(tag!=null)
            {
                int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);;
            }
            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
            dropTarget.setOnDragListener(null);
            if(screen == 1 || screen == 4)
            {
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Black")  || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Yellow"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousosmart);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Blue") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Gray"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.welldone);
                    mp.start();
                }
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("White") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Red"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Well Done.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousogood);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
            if(screen == 2 || screen == 5)
            {
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Black") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Yellow"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousosmart);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Blue") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Gray"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.welldone);
                    mp.start();
                }
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Red") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Pink"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Well Done.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousogood);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
            if(screen == 3 || screen == 6)
            {
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Yellow") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Chocolate"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousosmart);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Blue") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Gray"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Good Job.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.welldone);
                    mp.start();
                }
                if(dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Red") || dropTarget.getText().toString().equals("Pink"))
                {
                    //speakWords("Well Done.");
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yousogood);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[View.setOnDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnDragListener%28android.view.View.OnDragListener%29) was added in API 11 (Honeycomb) and is not available on Android 2.3.x devices, hence why you need the `SuppressLint("NewApi")` annotations (which are trying to warn you that the APIs you are expecting do not exist on all devices, causing runtime errors when you attempt to call them).

Comment: So, I have to remove SuppressLint("NewApi") from all of my activity? .. Okay, I do it now. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Right, without the SupressLint you'll know what calls do not exist on previous versions of Android and what you'll need to work around